# MySQL update same email with different name to make same name

Tags: mysql

I have situation. I have table feedback with fields email, name, feedback and some records with same email but the name different, like below:

```
id     email                name                 feedback
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2      test1@gmail.com      test1                test feedback
3      test2@gmail.com      test2                test2 feedback
4      test1@gmail.com      test123              another feedback 
5      test4@gmail.com      test4                test4 feedback
6      test1@gmail.com      test1235             test2 feedback
7      test4@gmail.com      test4254             test4 feedback
8      test4@gmail.com      test587              test4 feedback
```

you can see above for email test4@gmail.com and test1@gmail.com. Similarly there are much of records on table. Its complex to edit one by one. So I want if any query to update records to set either of name (from multiple names) can be set for same email.

is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Set it how exactly? Can you give expected output based on the above input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think This is what you need exactly and **tested**

```
update feedback f1 ,(select DISTINCT email,name from feedback ) f2 set f1.name=f2.name where f1.email=f2.email;
```